# Close flatpickr automatically when date is selected

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I am using [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) library.
What I have observed is that when `enableTime:false`, if you select the date, flatpickr closes automatically.

But when `enableTime:true`, it does not closes itself after selecting date, probably because user has to select the time after selecting the date.

Is there any work around to make it close as soon as the date is selected.

I even tried closing manually but this does not seems to work.

```
  var config = {
    locale: null,
    maxDate: "today",
    altInput: true,
    enableTime: true,
    minDate: document.getElementById("start_date_id").value,
    altFormat: "d-m-Y G:i K",
    dateFormat: "Z",
    from: null,
    to: null,
    wrap: true,
  };
  let start_flatpickr = flatpickr(document.getElementById("div_end_date_id"), config);
  start_flatpickr.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use on change method

```
public dateTimeOptions: FlatpickrOptions = {
    inline: false,
    wrap: true,
    enableTime: true,
    defaultDate: '',
    minDate: 'today',
    noCalendar: false,
    onChange: (selectedDates: Date[], dateStr: string, instance: any) => {
      // Close the Flatpickr instance when a date is selected
      instance.close();
    },
  }
```